# display an image from File path in xamarin

Tags: c#, image, url, xamarin, filepath

I am trying to display image from the path. I can display the image if i move the image to drawable but i want to display am image from he image Path. I tried using imageBitMap with GetImageBitmapFromUrl("image path") but it only display a blank screen. The seconded way i tried is  Android.Net.Uri url = Android.Net.Uri.Parse( "the image path")

```
namespace SetPictureUrl
[Activity(Label = "SetPictureUrl", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);`{


        ImageView  imagen = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.demoImageView);
        //------------------ i tried but did not work. the screen is blank
        //  var imageBitmap = GetImageBitmapFromUrl("my image path");
        //  imagen.SetImageBitmap(imageBitmap);


        //---------------- i tried but did not work. the screen is blank
        Android.Net.Uri url = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("./HTC Desire 620/Internal storage/storage/emulated/0/test/fox.jpeg");
        imagen.SetImageURI(url);


        //----- this work but is not the way i wish to do it. my main program work with file paths 
        // imagen.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.fox);

    }
```

i tried calling the path in view way but does not seem to make a difference 
example:

(./HTC Desire 620/Internal storage/storage/emulated/0/test/fox.jpeg)

,(HTC Desire 620/Internal storage/storage/emulated/0/test/fox.jpeg)

and (¬/HTC Desire 620/Internal storage/storage/emulated/0/test/fox.jpeg)

but no joy. I would love any help. Unsure why this giving me so much issue/

Comment: Where do you get the path from? `/HTC Desire 620/Internal Storage` does not exist on any phone...

Comment: i display the path i got from taking the picture and also check it with looking at my phone memory on my phone. they match up

Comment: Not sure how you check the phone memory, but the correct path in this case would be: `/storage/emulated/0/test/fox.jpeg`

Comment: thank you. but still not much luck. You were right in your correction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try this ?

```
                Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(new Java.IO.File(filePath));

                System.IO.Stream input = this.ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(uri);

                //Use bitarray to use less memory                    
                byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    int read;
                    while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                    }
                    pictByteArray = ms.ToArray();
                }

                input.Close();

                //Get file information
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options { InJustDecodeBounds = true };
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(pictByteArray, 0, pictByteArray.Length, options);

                imagen.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: System.IO.Stream input = Context.ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(uri);

is context a capital or not. i get error with ether way

Comment: Sorry, context was a custom variable. It is the Activity, so in your case it would be this.ContentResolver. I've updated my answer

Comment: thank you. what does [16 * 1024] stand for. if you don't mind me asking for

Comment: Hard to explain for me. Maybe this could help you to anderstand : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/345105/Memory-Stream-Multiplexer-write-and-read-from-many I used the default code from John Miller https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/84232/convert-image-to-byte-array-and-convert-byte-array-to-image-in-xamarin-forms

Comment: You're welcome ! I'm happy to help. Accepting my answer would be a pledge of recognition :)

Comment: Could you, please, update your answer, cause `ContentResolver` has been changed and doesn't contain `OpenInputStream(uri)` anymore?