# How to set Image.Source to a photo from internal storage Pictures folder?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

Here's what I have so far:

```
var file = Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures + "/test1.jpg";
ImagePhoto.Source = ImageSource.FromFile(file);
```

However, no image is being set. I've double checked that the test1.jpg file exists in the device's local storage Pictures folder, and it's there when I navigate to it using File Commander. Can anyone help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [display an image from File path in xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42627655/display-an-image-from-file-path-in-xamarin)

Comment: I don't think so. My issue relates to xamarin.forms, not xamarin for android.

Comment: What about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45774719/xamarin-forms-backgroundimage-from-external-storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this using the Environment variables:

```
var file = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory + "/" + Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures + "/test1.jpg";
```